# Solving an unusual equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, problem-solving, real-numbers, geometric-series

I need to find a real number $n$ such that $n > 1$ and:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^k}{n^k} = \frac{n-1}{n}
$$

Ideally, I'd find the minimum such $n$ (if more than one exists), but really, any such $n$ will do.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to solve this equation for $n$!  Are there any strategies I might be missing?

Comment: @What is the answer you're supposed to get?

Comment: @DigitalBrain This isn't a homework problem, so there is no answer I'm "supposed" to get.

Comment: Now take a look at answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{n^k}=\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^3+\cdots+\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^\infty$$

Common Ratio is $\frac{2}{n}$ So, This will converge when $|n|>2$.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{n^k}=\frac{\frac{2}{n}}{1-\frac{2}{n}}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{n^k}=\frac{\frac{2}{n}}{1-\frac{2}{n}}=\frac{2}{n-2}$$

It's all easy then $$\frac{2}{n-2}=\frac{n-1}{n}$$ gives quadratic in n $$n^2-5n+2=0$$
since $n>2$ we get $$n=\frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!  I don't know how I forgot that formula for geometric sums.  :)

Answer (score 3):

We can begin by considering the series:

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty{ x^k } \tag{1}$$

$$\frac{1}{1-x} - 1 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty{ x^k } \tag{2}$$

Then let $x=\frac{2}{n}$:

$$\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)} - 1 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty{ \left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^k } \tag{3}$$

Now we have the desired sum, and we want this equal to $\frac{n-1}{n}$:

$$\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)} - 1 = \frac{n-1}{n} \tag{4}$$

You can probably guess how to proceed from here.  Wolfram Alpha gives [these answers](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281-2%2Fn%29-1%3D%3D%28n-1%29%2Fn):

Solving for $n$, we get:

$$n=\begin{cases}
\frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2} \\
\frac{5-\sqrt{17}}{2}
\end{cases} \tag{5}$$

Of course, the greater value is $\frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}$.

Comment: Solving for $n$ we get $(5 \pm \sqrt{17})/2$.

Comment: @DigitalBrain I just realized your answer implicitly assumes $k$ starts at $0$, but it actually starts at $1$.  I think Matt Groff is correct.

Comment: @posilon:  I added Wolfram Alpha page to show calculations.

Comment: @DigitalBrain:  I added Wolfram Alpha page to show calculations.

Comment: @DigitalBrain: Your answer seems fine.

Comment: @MattGroff: You have the numerator and denominator switched at the right hand side of the equation you put in Wolfram Alpha. (And your link doesn't work.)

Comment: @posilon:  You're correct.  Sorry - I fixed it and both answers now give the same result.

Comment: @MattGroff Obviously this is Mathematics and not Politics

Comment: @MattGroff: You should also note that for $n=(5-\sqrt{17})/2$ the series diverges, as DigitalBrain suggests, so $n=(5+\sqrt{17})/2$ is not just the greatest solution but the only one.